# Bogus counts showing above inbox and achievements drop-down menus

Tags: support

For the last two days I have been seeing bogus counts of unread messages above inbox and achievements drop-down menus. Here is what they look like

[image: counts]

What is annoying is that, although they go away when I click on them, they keep coming back. All I need to do is click on any link that takes to another page on the site and they return. I thought it might be some kind cache corruption in my browser, but since seismatica posted in chat about having this problem, maybe it's a site issue.

I am using Safari 5.1.10 on OS X 10.6.8.

#### Update

It appears to fixed now (Sunday, August 17, 2014 5:58:48 PM EDT)

Comment: I have the same problem. Safari/Chrome, OSX 10.9.4.

Comment: Also had same problem (now appears resolved): Firefox, Windows 8